# How to fix div used by bootstrap with margin top and margin left

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I used a div that contains paragraphs and a href. But my problem is when I use a browser in a margin top  and a margin left it takes me a position and when I use another browser it takes me another position.
my code :

```
<div class="clearfix">
  <p style="position:absolute;font-size: 90%;margin-top: 7.2%"><a class="btn btn-info btn-xs" href="#"><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i>&nbsp;List materials</a></p>
  <p style="position:absolute;font-size: 90%;margin-top: 7.2%;margin-left: 18.4%"><a class="btn btn-info btn-xs"  href="#" ><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add material</a></p>
  <p style="position:absolute;font-size: 90%;margin-top: 7.2%;margin-left: 29%"><a class="btn btn-success btn-xs"  href="#" ><i class="fa fa-remove"></i>&nbsp;Update material </a></p>
</div>
```

**is what I can fix the position of div whatever the use of a browser?**

Answer (score 0):

Because you have assigned your `margin-top` and `left` in `percentage %`, that's why it differs. instead assign them in `px` and set you `body margin` and `padding` to `0`. Even at one point your all content gets mixed that's because of using `percentage %`, Try below codes.

```
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

<div class="clearfix">
  <p style="position:absolute;font-size: 90%;margin-top: 34px"><a class="btn btn-info btn-xs" href="#"><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i>&nbsp;List materials</a></p>
  <p style="position:absolute;font-size: 90%;margin-top: 34px;margin-left: 90px"><a class="btn btn-info btn-xs"  href="#" ><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add material</a></p>
  <p style="position:absolute;font-size: 90%;margin-top: 34px;margin-left: 180px"><a class="btn btn-success btn-xs"  href="#" ><i class="fa fa-remove"></i>&nbsp;Update material </a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: and when I use a computer station it takes me a position and when using a laptop it takes me another position.
**and you have an idea about this problem**

Comment: @johansson you try above codes, and why are you using class clearfix.

Comment: yes I used your code does it work but when I use a laptop it takes me another position

Comment: @johansson it's difficult to understand what you want, better create a jsfiddle of what you are doing and post again in detailed query

Comment: The problem with the screen is because the divs are sitting relative to the screen, so it *will* be in a different place on a 1920x1080 desktop (for instance) than a 1366x768 laptop. If you wrapped them in a `div`, which was a fixed, pixel based width, and it was set to `position: relative;` then they would be in the same place, provided the screen res wasn't smaller than the container.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest solution would be use pixels instead of %. % resizes according to screen which causes problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/3z5yqcz8/

```html
<div class="clearfix">
  <p style="position:absolute;font-size: 90%;margin-top: 7.2%"><a class="btn btn-info btn-xs" href="#"><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i>&nbsp;List materials</a></p>
  <p style="position:absolute;font-size: 90%;margin-top: 7.2%;margin-left: 200px;"><a class="btn btn-info btn-xs"  href="#" ><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Add material</a></p>
  <p style="position:absolute;font-size: 90%;margin-top: 7.2%;margin-left: 400px;"><a class="btn btn-success btn-xs"  href="#" ><i class="fa fa-remove"></i>&nbsp;Update material </a></p>
</div>
```